# problems with instaling mssql with php v7.2.7 using IIS

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I have this in my php.ini under [ExtensionList]

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts.dll
```

restarted web server, and php.info() does not show that `mssql` or `sqlsrv` is there.

I suspect that `sqlsrv_connect` is not working properly.

```
echo("disply msg here");
echo "\n";
$serverName = "tcp:name.dabase.windows.net,1433";    
$connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"database", 
                           "Uid"=>"userid", "PWD"=>"password");

//Establishes the connection
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, 
$connectionOptions);
echo("test");

if (!$conn) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' .  mysql_error()); 
} 
else
    echo("connected to database <p>    </p>");
```

Comment: try to print the error. add this   `die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));`

Comment: What are your Windows, IIS and PHP Driver for SQL Server versions? Thanks.